# Consuming an synchronous or asynchronous method as a Task

Tags: c#, async-await

I was looking at download manager type project on codeplex and came accross this one:
http://nthdownload.codeplex.com/

Browsing the code I ran across methods like `AddDownloads`, listed below:

`AddDownloads` starts the _downloadQueue.AddDownloads Task and continues with the `viewMaintenanceTask` Task.  If you look at the methods and things that happen in those 2 tasks and downstream it seems like everything is synchronous.

Also reading this blog post, [Synchronous tasks with Task](http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2012/03/synchronous-tasks-with-task.html) I'm trying to understand the advantage, if any, to wrapping synchronous methods in a `TaskCompletionSource`.  Is it because it gives the API consumer the option to start the task on a separate thread or simply because you want to consume the method as a `Task`.  Does a synchronous method wrapped in a `TaskCompletionSource` benefit from and parallel processing?

```
private Task<QueueOperation> AddDownloads(IEnumerable<IDownload> downloads, out Task<QueueOperation> startTask)
{
    var addTask = _downloadQueue.AddDownloads(downloads, out startTask);

    // Maintain views
    var viewMaintenanceTask = addTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.Exception == null)
        {
            var addedDownloads = t.Result.DownloadErrors.Where(k => k.Value == null).Select(k => k.Key).ToList();
            var activeDownloads = ActiveDownloads.ToList();
            AddToActiveDownloads(addedDownloads.Except(activeDownloads).ToList(), false);
        }
        else
        {
            // Rethrow exception, this ensures it'll bubble up to any further ContinueWith chained off this task
            throw t.Exception;
        }
        return t.Result;
    });

    return viewMaintenanceTask;
}
```

The example method from the blog post, wrapping a synchronous operation in a `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

try
{
    object result = model.Deserialize(stream, null, type);
    tcs.SetResult(result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    tcs.SetException(ex);
}

return tcs.Task;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does a synchronous method wrapped in a TaskCompletionSource benefit from and parallel processing?

No. Creating a `TaskCompletionSource` does *not* create a new thread in any way, shape or form.

The code you've given at the bottom is pretty pointless - the task will already be completed (or faulted) when the method returns. It would *only* be any use if you had to consume a task. I'd probably change it to:

```
try
{
    return Task.FromResult(model.Deserialize(stream, null, type));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // There's no Task.FromException, unfortunately.
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    tcs.SetException(ex);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

In C# it's the equivalent of writing an `async` method without an `await` expression:

```
public static async Task<object> Deserialize(Model model, Stream stream,
                                             Type type)
{
    return model.Deserialize(stream, null, type);
}
```

If you want genuine parallelism, you should use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194921.aspx) (.NET 4.5) or [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321455.aspx) (.NET 4).

Comment: So, not really any reason to wrap code in TCS in either of those examples.

Comment: Is awaiting synchronouse code wrapped in a TCS the same thing as calling it as you'd normally call a method?

Comment: @DerekBeattie: If the TCS has already completed, they're mostly equivalent. There are a very few subtle differences, but I doubt that they're applicable here.